# Android: StartActivityForResult to one Activity but return result in another

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

Currently, I have a problem to solve.

My application allow another application (Let say A) start my Application and get the result back.

Application A call:

```
 Intent sendIntent = 
 getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.package");

 sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sendIntent.setFlags(0);
 sendIntent.putExtra("amount", "20000");
 startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1);
```

Then my app will start MainActivity.
However, to getting result and send back to app A, I have to start some another Activities, Let say:

```
 MainActivity -> Activity B -> Activity C --> Activity D.
```

The result can be returned to App A from Activity C or Activity D.

Note that: I cannot use flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT because from B to C, I have called "startActivityForResult". (startActivityForResult and flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT  cannot going together).

Can you give me some ideas how to achieve this?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to get back result you can call activity B from MainActiviy and go to Activity C and then D

if you want to get back You should do that one by one and finish each activity and set result in onActivityResult.

do like this if you should get back to your Main activity :

```
    //in MainActivity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityB.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_MAIN_ACTIVITY);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MAIN_ACTIVITY && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        //maybe get back to application that called you 
    }
}

//in Second activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_B);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityC.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_B);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVITY_B && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}
```

and if you can directly Call First Application From Activity D
you may call the first Application and close your second app

Comment: If you finish MainActivity and goto Activivty B. The result Cancel is return to app A immediately.

Comment: No I mean something else, I will write down the code, please wait

Answer (score -1):

From your 1st Activity call the 2nd Activity using startActivityForResult() method

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In 2nd Activity if you want to send data back:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

If you don't want to return data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your 1st Activity class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the original question